# React link (using react router) in sidebar when clicked multiple times causes url param to repeat

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
   <ListItem
      style={{}}
      key={item.deviceId}
      component={Link}
      to={`device/${item.deviceId}`}
      button
```

The `` 'to={`device/${item.deviceId}`} `` causes the URL's params to become `www.example.com/device/device/device/device/1234id`.
This happens when I click on the button multiple times.

Comment: You are using a relative path to "device", instead of `device/` use `/device/` that will turn it into an absolute path based on the page domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change code below:

```
<ListItem
     style={{}}
     key={item.deviceId}
     component={Link}
     to={`/device/${item.deviceId}`} //add `/` before url
     ...
```